# npm install yarn not installing/ command not found

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code, npm-install, yarnpkg

So im trying to use yarn for something (i dont really understand this stuff tbh) but within the project, I do `npm install yarn` and it does something with no errors, but `yarn <anything>` doesnt work and says `command not found: yarn` , and then `npm install -g yarn` (also --global) throws this error and have no clue why this happens. Not familiar with paths and what not either.

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/*myname*/.npm/_logs/2021-11-27T21_44_09_137Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Have you tried running the command with elevated privileges?

Comment: @JannisMorgenstern what does that mean? Sorry, not quite knowledgeable on this sort of stuff

Comment: @absolutnoob It means that the command will be run as root (administrator on windows). Some operations need this because they change some settings / files that a normal user can not edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
```

Run the command as root (`sudo npm install -g yarn`) to install globally.

Comment: well i tried that but it didnt seem to work the way i wanted it to. Im trying to do something and i dont know why i have to but its part of the guide and i have to do `yarn install` then `yarn build` then `yarn bootstrap` but those didnt work. I used it in terminal then used those other commands within a project and it didnt work. Plus i dont really know what sudo does and dont wanna cloud up my storage and files and what